Randon sounds like a USB device is just plugged in but no USB device. Hope to attach video
I am getting random sounds like when a USB Device is plugged in. Everytime I get the beep the Bookmarks in Files jump and the activity light on my memory card reader lights. The bookmarks are to network devices. There are no USB devices plugged in. I do have a memory card reader that uses a USB connector. Can't find a way to upload a short video of the problem. I have Shutdown, Restarted but still there. This started last night. I have been running Ubuntu 24.01 for over 6 months and there was no updates last night.
Any suggestions would help.
